# ¿Cómo dirijo la página principal en caso de que ya haya iniciado sesión en flutter?

Tags: flutter

Es molesto iniciar sesión cada vez que abro mi aplicación, he intentado validar la sesión con shared_preferences enviando un verdadero si ya he iniciado sesión y falso si aún no lo he hecho, sin embargo, cuando intento redirigir a la página principal de mi aplicación, por alguna razón, onPressed no funciona en la página siguiente y no permite seguir desplazandome en otras paginas

Este es el código con el que hago la redirección

```
 import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'MemberPage.dart';
    import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

    String username = '';
    String profesion = '';
    String nivel = '';
    bool session = false;
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      ProgressDialog progressDialog;
      TextEditingController user = new TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController pass = new TextEditingController();
    
      String msg = '';
    
      Future<List> _login() async {
        final response = await http.get(
            "http://masciudad.com.co/flutter/login.php?username=" +
                user.text +
                "&password=" +
                pass.text);
    
        var datauser = json.decode(response.body);
    
        if (datauser.length == 0) {
          progressDialog.hide();
          setState(() {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              barrierDismissible: false,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text("Alerta"),
                content: Text("Usuario o contraseña incorrecta"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text("OK")),
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text("CANCEL"))
                ],
              ),
            );
          });
        } else {
          //Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/MemberPage');
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              '/MemberPage', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
          //Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/MemberPage');
          //Navigator.of(context).('/MemberPage');
    
          setState(() {
            username = datauser[0]['username'];
            profesion = datauser[0]['profesion'];
            nivel = datauser[0]['nivel'];
          });
    
          guardarPreferencias();
        }
        return datauser;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context, type: ProgressDialogType.Normal);
        progressDialog.style(message: 'Por favor espere...');
        verificoSesion();
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Pagina Principal"),
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Username",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                      controller: user,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Digite su usuario';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Username')),
                  Text(
                    "Password",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: pass,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Digite su contraseña';
                      }
                      // Use cualquier tamaño de contraseña que usted quiera aquí
                      if (value.length < 6) {
                        return 'El tamaño de la contraseña debe ser más de 6 carácteres';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Login"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      progressDialog.show();
                      _login();
                    },
                  ),
                  Text(
                    msg,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.red),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      guardarPreferencias() async {
        SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        preferences.setString("username2", username);
        preferences.setString("profesion", profesion);
        preferences.setString("nivel", nivel);
        preferences.setBool("session", true);
      }
    
      Future obtenerPreferencias() async {
        SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        setState(() {
          username2 = preferences.get("username2") ?? "";
          profesion = preferences.get("profesion") ?? "";
          nivel = preferences.get("nivel") ?? "";
          session = preferences.get("session");
        });
      }
    
      Future verificoSesion() async {
        obtenerPreferencias();
         if (session == true) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              '/MemberPage', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Esto es main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Modulos/MemberPage.dart';
import 'package:fluterproyecto1/Modulos/AdminPage.dart';
import 'Modulos/login.dart';
import 'package:fluterproyecto1/Modulos/DetalleUser.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MainPag());

class MainPag extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPag({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPagState createState() => _MainPagState();
}

class _MainPagState extends State<MainPag> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Login PHP My Admin',
      routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) => new MyHomePage(),
        '/MemberPage': (BuildContext context) => new MemberPage(),
        '/AdminPage': (BuildContext context) => new AdminPage(),
        '/DetalleUser': (BuildContext context) => new DetalleUser(),
      },
      //initialRoute: '/MyHomePage',
    );
  }
}
```

y esta es la página a la que redirijo cuando la aplicación encuentra que la sesión está activa

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:fluterproyecto1/Modulos/DetalleUser.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String username2 = '';
String profesion = '';

class MemberPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MemberPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MemberPageState createState() => _MemberPageState();
}

class _MemberPageState extends State<MemberPage> {
  Map data;
  List userData;
  ProgressDialog progressDialog;

  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get("http://masciudad.com.co/flutter/getdata.php");
    data = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      //progressDialog.show();
      userData = data["data"];
      //progressDialog.hide();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context, type: ProgressDialogType.Normal);
    progressDialog.style(message: 'Por favor espere...');

    setState(() {
      obtenerPreferencias();
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Bienvenido $username2"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: userData == null ? 0 : userData.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return InkWell(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    "assets/128.jpg",
                    width: 30.0,
                    height: 30.0,
                  ),
                  //CircleAvatar(
                  ///cuando la imagen es de interntet
                  //backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  //  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/follettkyle/128.jpg"),
                  //),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "${userData[index]["username"]} - ${userData[index]["profesion"]}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => new DetalleUser())),
          );
        },
      ),
      //Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      //  builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()));
      //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/MyHomePage");
    );
  }

  Future obtenerPreferencias() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      username2 = preferences.get("username2") ?? "";
      profesion = preferences.get("profesion") ?? "";
    });
  }

  Future destruirPreferencias() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preferences.clear();
  }
}
```

No entiendo por qué cuando la redirección se realiza, ninguna acción funciona.

Comment: deberías llamar a `obtenerPreferencias` en el initState , no lo hagas dentro del método build ya que te genera un bucle infinito por eso es que no puedes hacer nada.